# how to encode a sequence of symbols to numerical form without losing information?

Tags: string, encoding, neural-network, feature-extraction

I want to use a neural network to classify strings. the 'problem' is that neural networks accept numerical input, so I need a method of encoding a string into a numerical vector. is there a standard way of approaching such a problem?

i was thinking about counting n-grams, but this approach would result in huge feature vectors if i don't want to lose any information, since i'd need to compute everything from 1-grams to length-of-string-grams. right?

so, is there a more compact method of encoding strings to numerical data? one that maintains information about both frequency of symbols and their order?

Comment: How do you want classify them by which sign?

Comment: @YuraZaletskyy the classification criteria isn't an attribute of the string it self. each string represents a process, the classification should be done according to whether the process succeeded or not

Answer (score 0):

Might this be what you are searching for? 
https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/

You could vectorize words (and probably symbols) with word2vec, then add the vectors (or subtract them when facing a negation), then divide the result by the number of words added to "build the string" to do a kind of vectorial mean to scale that back. I have not tested this tool yet.

You also asked a question about the frequency and order of words in your strings. I think the order might be flushed away with this technique, but not their count.